# Merging Data in R

Tags: r

```
df1 <- data.frame(CustomerId = c(1:6), Product = c(rep("Honda",3), rep("Chevrolet",3)))

df2 <- data.frame(CustomerId = c(2, 4,7), State = c("Selangor","Sarawak","Kelantan"))
```

Task 1:
Return only the rows in which the df1 have matching keys in df2.

Task 2:
Return all rows from the df1, and any rows with matching keys from df2.

Task 3:
Return all rows from the df2, and any rows with matching keys from df1.

Comment: First, consider a `self-study` tag, at least read it's description. This will help getting good answers in the future. ( cf https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info ) Second, this is not on topic, as it is not about statistics but about a computer program. Try stackoverflow for this. Third: You should look into the `merge` command in R. Start by typing `help(merge)` in your R console and "R merge" into a www search engine of your choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely homework so no complete solution is to be given. Start with

```
> merge(df1, df2, by = "CustomerId")
  CustomerId   Product    State
1          2     Honda Selangor
2          4 Chevrolet  Sarawak
```

and work your way through the documentation and web pages on the `merge` command.